# Which driver for AMD Radeon 530 graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

I have a notebook with an AMD Radeon 530 graphics card. I was trying to install a driver but I none of the drivers (amdgpu or AMD-GPU pro) seemed to support that graphics card. Anyhow on the AMD [website](https://www.amd.com/de/products/graphics/radeon-530) it says it has Ubuntu support. Which driver should I install?

Comment: This is quite new hardware, you may just need newer versions of these drivers. PPAs for both are mentioned fairly extensively in the main answer on the suggested duplicate above.